# How to delete an answer that is incorrect

Tags: support

im trying to delete an answer to a question i posted because the answer does not answer the question i posted.

How can i do this on android application?

To further complicate matters ive been banned from editing my question to try and make it match the answer and the question has been closed while it racks up downvotes.

I either want to delete the question (by deleting the answer) or edit my question. I had previously tried deleting the text of the question since i had been instructed to delete it which is what lead to me being banned from editing it (i dont have a delete button ony android application and im still learning the ins and outs so i thought that deleting the text was how it was supposed to be done)

Any help would be appreciated.

Im having a difficult time with this question and just want it to go away.  This is my only source of negative points because i dont know how to ask my question correctly.  Ive earned quite a bit of points so if think there should be a moderator that is understanding out there

Some people are just mean and disagreeable

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to delete an answer you posted, or an answer someone else posted to a question of yours? If you mean the latter, you *definitely* can't do that, and certainly not on your own. For more details see [this Meta Stack Exchange FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/). If you don't like an answer to your question, you can (i) downvote it, and (ii) comment explaining why it doesn't fit the bill. If it's *really* off the mark, i.e. does not address the post at all and talks about something else entirely, you can flag it as Not An Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Q&A on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app), the Android app does not allow you to delete posts because some of the required infrastructure (like viewing deleted posts) is not implemented in the app.

Using the website, you can delete one of your answers by clicking the "delete" link under it. The exception is if the answer has been accepted; in that case, you won't see a "delete" link, and you're not allowed to delete it. See more information on deletion in [this mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Note that removing the text of a post with an edit is never acceptable.

---

Though in this case I believe you're asking how to delete someone *else's* answer. That's not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I learned the hard way that i cant delete my own question. I was told to delete it and when i tried (since i have no delete button on android) i tried deleting the text. I was tricked into doing this by dmckee. Im not sure what problem he/she has with me but thats what happened.  Nobody told me im not allowed to delete from android

Comment: So how do i get rid of my question or answer?  Sure stack exchange doesnt want questions with incorrect answers right?  But here we are...we have a question with an incorrect answer

Comment: Like, could someone edit the question to match the answer at the very least?  I asked the answerer to delete his/her answer

Comment: As shown by the upvotes on the answer, it's considered useful enough by the community to make it worth keeping. If you want to get rid of your question, you can ask people to review the answer (maybe ask in [chat]), and if they agree that it's incorrect, they'll downvote it. You are also allowed to ask the answerer to delete their answer, as you did, but of course it's up to them whether they want to do it.

Comment: But im one of the upvoters!  And presumably dmckee is the other since he has been messing with me!  I upvoted because i thought it was nice information.  I didnt know id be damned by it

Comment: I just want to be able to edit my question without it being changed back to the "unclear" version but im not allowed to.

Comment: This is the only source of negative points i get.  People got mad when i asked it and they wont leave it alone.  I feel like ive earned enough points for people to realize im not some hack

Comment: Those people that voted to close all have issues with me.  At the very least i should be allowed to edit my question as im seriously doubtfull those people will agree to open the question.  (The question is pretty damn clear as is....)

Comment: @user122066 See the chat room invitation I sent you.